# JVM Heap Size error in Langton's ant

Tags: java, jvm

I was trying to make a Langton's ant (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langton's_ant) program in Java.I initially thought of a naive implementation with just two colors - and hence a boolean grid- or a boolean 2D Array .

There seems to be a problem here- The grid  needs to be constructed  at run time- that is, the user enters the value of the length of the grid.

Which means i can't take a grid value more than a particular value - as it will throw a Out of memory error on Java heap.

Typical grid that i can make at max is (30,000*30,0000).

I was thinking about ways to get around this problem to atleast make the grid reach 2^32*2^32..

Can someone offer suggestions to improvise the algorithm? Or any other optimization?

Though my question is specific to one particular problem...I Guess Strategies to get around this issue may match in many such problems .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to allocate and hold a matrix in memory for this. You can maintain the visited positions only, in a list of nodes. A node will have information like: `x` and `y` coordinates (from the virtual matrix) and the `color`. 
This way your ant will only need to know her position (`x` and `y`)in the virtual matrix and the direction that needs to follow will be computed based on the color of the node that the ant sits on.